# Responsive table, possible for nested table cell widths to inherit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, responsive

I've got a responsive table, which has different content in each row and a concertina mechanism on each row.

The concertina essentially adds another table row beneath that current row, which has a td with a colspan for the amount of cells in the table.

Inside this concertina I have another table which I need the table cells to line up with the parent table. I appreciate this probably isn't possible with HTML/CSS alone and probably needs to be done with JS?

Or is there another way?

I can't post all my code here but here is a screenshot of what I mean

[image]

```
<table class="parent-table">
<tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
    <td>Cell 5</td>
    <td>Cell 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="concertina">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Other 1</td>
                    <td>Other 2</td>
                    <td>Other 3</td>
                    <td>Other 4</td>
                    <td>Other 5</td>
                    <td>Other 6</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer would be 'No', not possible just with HTML/CSS. I myself am working on a fixed-header, scrollable table with resizable columns, plus double-click column header border to autofit. It's far from complete, and I can tell you if that is roughly the direction you might be heading, you might want to take a deep breath.

**UPDATES BELOW**

Judging from the screenshot, have you considered revising the HTML structure?

From the markup below, you have multiple `<tbody>` sections, each with a first `<tr>` that contains `<th>` elements. The rest would be showing details data, rows of `<tr>` that contains typical `<td>` elements.

In jQuery, you can use `$('tr:has(th)')` to select the header row, and `$('tr:has(td)')` to select the data rows.

The last `<th>` in the header would house your "More/Less" control, which simply shows/hides the subsequent data rows.

Would this work for you instead?

```html
<table class="master-table">
        <tbody class="concertina">
            <tr>
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <th>Header 3</th>
                <th>Header 4</th>
                <th>Header 5</th>
                <th>Header 6</th>
                <th>More</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
                <td>Cell 4</td>
                <td>Cell 5</td>
                <td colspan="2">Cell 6</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="concertina">
            <tr>
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <th>Header 3</th>
                <th>Header 4</th>
                <th>Header 5</th>
                <th>Header 6</th>
                <th>More</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
                <td>Cell 4</td>
                <td>Cell 5</td>
                <td colspan="2">Cell 6</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: ah i think a lot of people are going to misunderstand me, this jsfiddle was literally just to show the structure of the table, each row of my actual table has different content in the cells, so the table inside the concertina doesn't really know what width to make its' cells

Comment: Well in that case, may I first ask why you need this nested table structure, rather than having it as one table?

Comment: i've added a screenshot of my site to show you, what would you suggest? as it needs to be a concertina system

Comment: I see. Short answer would be 'No', not possible just with HTML/CSS. I myself am working on a fixed-header, scrollable table with resizable columns, plus double-click column header border to autofit. It's far from complete, and I can tell you if that is roughly the direction you might be heading, you might want to take a deep breath.

Comment: yeah i thought so! already taken a few deep breaths...! thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give you a full or even partial solution. I've modified my answer in case the initial one may mislead other readers.

Comment: I think the point here is he needs a 'responsive' table layout, so any change of widths of any column needs to be reflected in all `td` cells across the separate tables. There are lots of good jQuery grid plugins out there, like Flexigrid for example (http://flexigrid.info/), but most of these that I've seen don't have a 'flexible container width' in mind.

Comment: exactly right Terry, what I'm going to do is repeat the table headers in the concertina for now

Comment: It's still possible to have your table as just one table. As far as I can tell, the 'More/Less' "buttons" in your screenshot would simply be showing/hiding certain rows. The 'second' row where it says "Correction History" and "Date of correction", now *that* can be either a nested table, or cells with colspans.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your tables using this bit of CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Then you will have to set the width of the `<td>`s

Comment: i don't think that'll solve my problem, as I said my jsfiddle doesn't truly represent my site, was just really to show the structure of my html

Comment: You can give each `<td>` in each `table` a `class` of something like `column-1`, `column-2` etc. Then set the widths accordingly.

Comment: Also, the child table should be set to stretch the full 100% of it's 80% wide parent.